# Jquery error not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have been working on a ticker, and now it is broken. What have i done wrong, and how do i fix it? www.codtelevision.com

I have added `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: all that's left to do is everything

Comment: He provided the link - easy enough to find the source and just go through it. Probably better than being limited to whatever info he gives us thinking that is all that is relevant... that's my two cents on the whole "paste the code" thing, because sometimes you need the whole picture.

Comment: @jeffkee thanks! No one else realizes, pasting the whole source code would be stupid

Answer (score 1):

The jquery-latest.js should be called BEFORE the jqueryUI code is called. Sequence matters.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I see this error with Firebug and it comes from jQuery UI file:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

...=="hidden")return false;e=e&&e==="left"?"scrollLeft":"scrollTop";var a=false;if(..
```

Changes are you are referencing the jQuery UI script before jQuery itself. As jQuery UI depends on jQuery you must reference the scripts in the correct order, that is, jQuery first then jQuery UI.

Yes, you're referencing jQuery UI first with your current code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://www.codtelevision.com/nivo/css/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
```

Try this way:

```
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://www.codtelevision.com/nivo/css/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: 8 Seconds apart! Yup the sequences was it - looked at the source code on the page.

Comment: Well, now what I see in Firegub is this error: `TypeError: document.getElementById("homeLink") is null
[Break On This Error]  

document.getElementById('homeLink').className="active";`

Comment: Try $('homelink') as a selector instead. It's a softer way to select, and there's built-in exceptions in case the item is not there.